# Powershell: I'm unable to delete a line from a text file

Tags: powershell

Here's a method for deleting a line that I thought would work

```
#earlier in the script
$inFile = Get-Content -Path ".\input.txt"

# ...Later... #

$inFile = Get-Content -path ".\input.txt" | where-object {$_ -notmatch $line}
set-content -path ".\input.txt" -Value $inFile
```

The problem is that the -notmatch parameter doesn't seem to work. The Get-Content cmdlet just copies all the content from input.txt, including $line. I've also tried changing the code to clear $inFile completley and create a temporary holder, but no dice.

```
Clear-Variable -name "inFile"
$holder = Get-Content -path ".\input.txt" | where-object {$_ -notmatch $line}
set-content -path ".\input.txt" -Value $holder
$inFile = Get-Content -path ".\input.txt"
```

Am I using -notmatch incorrectly? Here's the full text script for context.

```
Write-Host "Starting"

[bool] $keepRunning = 1
[bool] $everFound = 0
[bool] $searchComplete = 0
:main while($keepRunning)
{
    $inFile = Get-Content -path ".\input.txt"
    $completed = Get-Content -Path ".\output.txt"
    $line = $inFile[0]
    $holder
    if($inFile.count -eq 1)
    {
        $line = $inFile
    }

    # create condition to check if $line matches any line in completed.txt
    # if it does, skip this line and move on to the next line
    :search while($everFound -eq 0 -and $searchComplete -eq 0)
    {
        #Write-Host "Outer loop"
        foreach($url in $completed)
        {
            #Write-Host $line
            #write-host $url

            if ($line -eq $url)
            {
                Write-Host "`nThis file was already downloaded --Skipping to the next line"
                $inFile = Get-Content -path ".\input.txt" | where-object {$_ -notmatch $line}
                set-content -path ".\input.txt" -Value $inFile
                $inFile = Get-Content -path ".\input.txt"
                $line = $inFile[0]
                $everFound = 1
                break
            }
        }
        if ($everFound -eq 1)
        {
            break
        }
        $searchComplete = 1
        Write-Host "Search Complete`n"
    }
    Write-Host "Before the download--------"

    Write-Host $everFound
    Write-Host $searchComplete

    if ($everFound -eq 0 -and $searchComplete -eq 1)
    {
        #download the files
        $downloadCommand = "youtube-dl.exe --verbose --cookies .\cookies.txt `"$line`""
        get-date
        invoke-Expression $downloadCommand

        #delete the url
        add-content -Path ".\output.txt" -Value $line
        $inFile = Get-Content -path ".\input.txt" | where-object {$_ -notmatch $line} 
        set-content -path ".\input.txt" -Value $inFile
        write-host "`n"

        get-date
        Write-Host "Sleeping for 45mins"
        #start-sleep -s 2700
    }
    $everFound = 0
    $searchComplete = 0
    Write-Host "-------------After the download!!"
    Write-Host $everFound
    Write-Host $searchComplete

    # check if the file is empty. If it is, set the keepRunning flag to false and exit the main while loop
    if($Null -eq $inFile)
    {
        $keepRunning = 0
    }
}

Write-Host "Done"
Read-Host "Press the Enter Key to Exit"
```

EDIT:
$inFile contains a list of youtube URLs on each line. $line is assigned the value of the first line of $inFile

```
$line = $inFile[0]
```

Here is a youtube URL: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB5zlHMsM7k`

I also added some statements to output the values of $line right before the file. Someone please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I using `-notmatch` incorrectly?

You're using it incorrectly, if `$line` contains a substring to search for *literally* (as-is, verbatim) in the input file's lines, and that substring happens to contain *regex metacharacters*, such as `.` and `$`.

To use `-match` / `-notmatch` for *literal* substring matching, you must *escape* the substring:

```
$_ -notmatch [regex]::Escape($line)
```

If you want to match lines only *in full*, you must *anchor* the regex:

```
$_ -notmatch ('^' + [regex]::Escape($line) + '$')
```

---

Note that PowerShell has no operator for *literal* substring matching.

However, the [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) (`[string]`) type has a `.Contains()` method for literal substring matching, but not that, unlike PowerShell's operators, it is case-*sensitive* by default (there are overloads for case-insensitive matching, but only in PowerShell (Core) 7+):

```
-not $_.Contains($line) # case-sensitive, literal substring matching

# PS 7+ only: case-INsensitive, literal substring matching
-not $_.Contains($line, 'CurrentCultureIgnoreCase')
```

For full-line matching:

```
-not ($_.Length -eq $line.Length -and $_.Contains($line))
```

or:

```
-not $_.Equals($line, 'CurrentCultureIgnoreCase')
```

The advantage of using `.Contains()` is that it performs better than `-match`, though the latter offers much more flexibility.